# Google maps getting the North West and South East long and lat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Angular Google maps, documentation here
https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/GoogleMapApi

I'm simply trying to find out what the current lng and lat are on the map and then get a callback if they change.

I'm loading the map like so:

```
// uiGmapGoogleMapApi is a promise.
// The "then" callback function provides the google.maps object.
uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(map) {
    console.log(map);
});
```

On logging the maps object I get the following:
[image: log results]

I'd assume that **LatLngBounds** would give me the bounds that I'm looking for and reading the documentation I can see it at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference

My problem is, calling anything is undefined. One would simply think that there would be nice simple functions for this sort of thing but it does not seem so.

Now I'm stuck. The angular documentation almost useless and the gmaps documentation doesn't relate.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to deal with this situation is to use ready made Directives.

For example make use of this particular [directive](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) available open sourced on GitHub. I have used this to set the bounds and also detect the changes in the current bounds. There is no heavy lifting that you have to do at your end.

Just need to call the regular Javascript calls like for;

- zoom: 'zoom_changed','bounds_changed'.
- When the bounds are changed due to drag: 'drag', 'center_changed', 'bounds_changed'

Then, just use this as an event with prefix 'on-', for example;

```
<map center="0,0" on-bounds_changed="handleFunc()"></map>
```

Hope this Helps!